# Polling Stateless Java Web Service for Progress

Tags: java, web-services, jndi, polling

I have created a stateless web service that is injected into my client code using JNDI. Lets call that Web Service A.

Web Service B, I did not create and has limitations. 5 searches per session, and only 1 search every 2 seconds.

Web Service A has a method that gathers all results from Web Service B, and is a long running process (Could be 10-100 calls to Web Service B)

I would like to update my UI using a Progress Bar, but as of right now I'm not sure how to poll Web Service A in such a way that it continually interfaces with Web Service B. I would think that i would have to use two threads to access the same injected object.

Should I just change Web Service A to be Stateful? Asynchronous and use Futures?

Help?